# customCheckedListBox CheckedChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I've made `customCheckedListBox`, which I want to use to filter `dataGridView` with mulitselect option. I would like to be able to catch `CheckedListBox` `CheckedChange` state, but `CheckedListBox` only supports `ItemCheck` event.

Here is my code:

```
private void customCheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
   FilterDataGrid();
}

private void FilterDataGrid()
{
    var list4 = customCheckedListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
    if (customCheckedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
       var result = list3.Where(Srodek => list4.Any(x => x == Srodek.Srodek.category1));
         DataTable ListAsDataTable3 = BuildDataTable2<CalaLinijka>(result);
         DataView ListAsDataView3 = ListAsDataTable3.DefaultView;
         dataGridView4.DataSource = view = ListAsDataView3;
    }
```

}

Problem is that `ItemCheck` event can handle only one choice, so even when user decided to choose more than one opiton it will show only first selected item. I guess that `CheckedChanged` event would work in my case, but when `ItemCheck` event is called there are no `CheckedItems` yet. They become "Checked" after `ItemCheck` event is finished. So when it goes inside `FilterDataGrid` `CheckedChanged.Count` equals to 0.

My question is how should I handle `CheckedChanged` event in `CheckedListBox`. I hope that I didn't messed up too much. If there will be any questions, just let me know and I will try to expain more.

Comment: Loop through all the items and check for the `Checked` property.

Comment: Ok, I did it this way. Now I will check if everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using foreach loop (just like KingKing suggested) and putting it inside `MouseLeave` event.

```
private void customCheckedListBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string itemChecked in customCheckedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        CheckedList.Add(itemChecked);
    }
    FilterDataGrid();
}
```